# Error converting data type varchar to float. c# webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I am creating a web app using c#,

Here is my webservice for saving a record

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public void saverecd(string id, string particular,string amt,string adjamt,string tdate, string total, string date, string utrno, string modeofpayment, string transferdate,string trainer, string typeofadj, string bnkid)
{
    List<string> td = tdate.Split(',').ToList();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string t in td)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into finalinstructoreexpense(sonvinid,particulars,amount,totalamt,date,utno,paymentid,paymode,issuedate,sondate,trainer,type,bank_id) values('@sonvinid','@particulars','@amount','@totalamt','@date','@utno','@paymentid','@paymode','@issuedate','@sondate','@trainer','@type','@bank_id')", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value =Convert.ToInt32(id);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@particular", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = particular;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@amount",SqlDbType.Float).Value=adjamt.Split(',')[i];
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@totalamt", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = total;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date.Split(',')[i];
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@utno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = utrno;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@paymentid",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=paymentid;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@paymode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = modeofpayment;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@issuedate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = transferdate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@sondate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = t;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@trainer", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = trainer;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = typeofadj;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@bank_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(bnkid);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        message = "Adjusted Amount Inserted Successfully";
        con.Close();
    }

}
```

i don't know what is wrong with this code,

this is what i enter in web service

> Parameter Value id:    0 particular:   0001 amt:   10 adjamt:  10 tdate:
>   01-01-2013,01-01-2013 total:   20 date:    01-01-2013 utrno:   test
>   modeofpayment:     test transferdate:  01-01-2013 trainer:     ibrahim
>   shaikh typeofadj:  adjust bnkid:
>   Invoke

and following is the error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error converting data type varchar to float.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at mvcerp2.newpayment.saverecd(String id, String particular, String amt, String adjamt, String tdate, String total, String date, String utrno, String modeofpayment, String transferdate, String trainer, String typeofadj, String bnkid) in Z:\mvcerp2\mvcerp2\newpayment.asmx.cs:line 135
```

Comment: Please start by reducing this to *just* the parameter which is causing the problem - you can find that out, but we can't easily. Additionally, in future, please take the time to format the code clearly, without any extraneous indentation. It doesn't take long to do, but it makes all the difference in readability.

Comment: One of your columns is a float and you're passing a string.  Didn't you even look at the error message?

Comment: sorry sir for that will remember this for next post

Comment: Every parameter placeholder in your query is inside single quotes. This transform these placeholders in literal strings. The parameters are non used at all here. Remove the single quotes around the placeholders and then retry (Not sure if this will fix the problem though because still a float need to be passed as float not as a string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your SQL, which I've reformatted here to avoid a single huge line:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SQlCommand(
    @"insert into finalinstructoreexpense
      (sonvinid,particulars,amount,totalamt,date,
       utno,paymentid,paymode,issuedate,sondate,trainer,type,bank_id) 
      values('@sonvinid','@particulars','@amount','@totalamt','@date',
             '@utno','@paymentid','@paymode','@issuedate','@sondate','@trainer',
             '@type','@bank_id')",
    con);
```

That SQL doesn't contain any parameters. Instead, it contains quoted string values of "@sonvinid" etc. You need to remove the quotes around your parameter names:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SQlCommand(
    @"insert into finalinstructoreexpense
      (sonvinid, particulars, amount, totalamt, date,
       utno, paymentid, paymode, issuedate, sondate, trainer, type, bank_id) 
      values(@sonvinid, @particulars, @amount, @totalamt, @date,
             @utno, @paymentid, @paymode, @issuedate, @sondate, @trainer,
             @type, @bank_id)",
    con);
```

At that point, each value really is a parameter, which is what you want.

(I've added spaces in as well to make it more readable.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should have the single quotes around your parameter names in the SQL statement.

```
values('@sonvinid','@particulars','@amount','@totalamt','@date','@utno','@paymentid','@paymode','@issuedate','@sondate','@trainer','@type','@bank_id')", con);
```

Should be:

```
values(@sonvinid,@particulars .... etc.
```

With the single quotes these will be interpreted as strings rather than as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I dare to improve a bit on the answer from John Skeet above because there are other issues in your code that need to be addressed.

First issue is the fact that you pass to your parameters of type DateTime or Float a string. This could work or not depending what is the input and what the database engine thinks to do to transform a string in the appropriate value for the column.

Take for example the float value. If you pass a simple value like 10 all is well, but if you pass a value like 10,5 (a valid floating "string" in some locales) and your database engine tries to convert it in its DIFFERENT locale you end up with a truncation or an error. The same (and with more probability) happens with dates. With "1/1/2013" all is well, but what if the string is "25/1/2013" and the database engine use a MM/d/yyyy locale for dates? Again a failure waiting to happen.

I really suggest you to take control of these issues with an appropriate conversion to the specific type and a sanity check before adding the values to the parameters collection as you alredy do with the Int.

The second issue lies in the foreach loop. Your input value for *tdate* is "01-01-2013,01-01-2013", so your loop runs two times and inserts two records. If this is correct or not I don't know but the problem are the values for *adjamt* and *date* that contains just one element (not two) but you still split them like the *tdate* parameter. The code doesn't trigger an *Index Out Of Range Exception* just because you use the variable *i* inside your loop without incrementing it. Again, this seems to be incorrect.